# How to correctly pass through argument of object type with var prefix?

Tags: delphi, object, arguments, var, aggpas

**Summarization:**

```
type 
  MyObject = object
  end;

  MyRecord = record
  end;

  MyClass = class
  end;

  procedure ProcA(aMyObject: MyObject);
  procedure ProcB(var aMyObject: MyObject);
  procedure ProcC(aMyRecord: MyRecord);
  procedure ProcD(var aMyRecord: MyRecord);
  procedure ProcE(aMyClass: MyOClass);
  procedure ProcF(var aMyClass: MyClass);
```

1. `MyObject` and `MyRecord` are value type, whereas `MyClass` is reference type.
2. Assignment of variable of value type will copy the variable; assignment of variable of reference type will copy the reference.
3. The arguments in `ProcA` and `ProcC` are copies of the original ones.
4. The arguments in `ProcB` and `ProcD` are the original ones.
5. The argument in `ProcE` is a copy of the original reference.
6. The argument in `ProcF` is the original reference.
7. Regarding how to wrap up Agg2D object, which is declared in the unit agg_2D.pas, to draw, please see David's answer below.

===========================================
I am learning to use the AggPas which is a pure-pascal vector graphics drawing API. Specifically the unit agg_2D.pas, which contains Agg2D object, is used instead of the unit Agg2D.pas, which contains TAgg2D class. The reason of choosing the unit agg_2D.pas over the unit Agg2D.pas is for cross-platform ability.

However, I cannot correctly pass through argument of Agg2D object type with var prefix. As shown in the following code, I want to pass the Agg2D object created by TForm1 to another class that is actual responsible to draw shapes. However, it does not work. Could you help to comment on the possible reason? It seems I must have missed important concepts regarding object type. Any suggestion is appreciated! You could new a VCL application, attach the FormCreate handler, and comment out the drawing codes line by line to see the effect.

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      agg_2D,
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs;

    type
      TRenderEngine_BMP = class;
      TRenderEngine_Agg = class;
      TForm1 = class;

      TRenderEngine_BMP = class
      private
        fBMP: TBitmap;
      public
        constructor Create(var aBMP: TBitmap);
        procedure DrawEllipse;
      end;

      TRenderEngine_Agg = class
      private
        fVG: Agg2D;
      public
        constructor Create(var aVG: Agg2D);
        procedure DrawEllipse;
      end;

      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }

        fBMP: TBitmap;
        fVG: Agg2D;
        fEngine_BMP: TRenderEngine_BMP;
        fEngine_Agg: TRenderEngine_Agg;

        procedure AttachBMP(var aVG: Agg2D; var aBMP: TBitmap);
        procedure OnSceneResize(Sender: TObject);
        procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    uses
      Math;

    { TRenderEngine_BMP }

    constructor TRenderEngine_BMP.Create(var aBMP: TBitmap);
    begin
      Self.fBMP := aBMP;
    end;

    procedure TRenderEngine_BMP.DrawEllipse;
    begin
      Self.fBMP.Canvas.ellipse(20, 20, 80, 80);
    end;

    { TRenderEngine_Agg }

    constructor TRenderEngine_Agg.Create(var aVG: Agg2D);
    begin
      Self.fVG := aVG;
    end;

    procedure TRenderEngine_Agg.DrawEllipse;
    begin
      Self.fVG.ellipse(50, 50, 30, 30);
    end;

    { TForm1 }

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.OnResize := {$IFDEF FPC} @ {$ENDIF} OnSceneResize;
      Self.OnPaint := {$IFDEF FPC} @ {$ENDIF} OnScenePaint;

      fBMP := TBitmap.Create;
      fBMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      fBMP.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      fBMP.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
      fBMP.Width := ClientWidth;
      fBMP.Height := ClientHeight;

      fVG.Construct;
      Self.AttachBMP(fVG, fBMP);

      fEngine_BMP := TRenderEngine_BMP.Create(fBMP);
      fEngine_Agg := TRenderEngine_Agg.Create(fVG);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.AttachBMP(var aVG: Agg2D; var aBMP: TBitmap);
    var
      tmpBuffer: pointer;
      tmpStride: integer;
    begin
      tmpStride := integer(aBMP.ScanLine[1]) - integer(aBMP.ScanLine[0]);

      if tmpStride < 0 then
        tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[aBMP.Height - 1]
      else
        tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[0];

      aVG.attach(tmpBuffer, aBMP.Width, aBMP.Height, tmpStride);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.fBMP.Canvas.FillRect(Self.ClientRect);

    //  Self.fBMP.Canvas.ellipse(20, 20, 80, 80);  // Work
    //  Self.fVG.ellipse(50, 50, 30, 30);          // Work
    //  Self.fEngine_BMP.DrawEllipse;              // Work
      Self.fEngine_Agg.DrawEllipse;                // Do not work

      Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, fBMP);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnSceneResize(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      fBMP.Width := IfThen(ClientWidth > 0, ClientWidth, 2);
      fBMP.Height := IfThen(ClientHeight > 0, ClientHeight, 2);

      Self.AttachBMP(fVG, fBMP);
    end;

    end.
```

If I delete all occurrences of the var prefix of procedure arguments, the second circle-drawing code also stops working, which I don't quite understand. The unit is shown as below for your convenience:

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      agg_2D,
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs;

    type
      TRenderEngine_BMP = class;
      TRenderEngine_Agg = class;
      TForm1 = class;

      TRenderEngine_BMP = class
      private
        fBMP: TBitmap;
      public
        constructor Create(aBMP: TBitmap);
        procedure DrawEllipse;
      end;

      TRenderEngine_Agg = class
      private
        fVG: Agg2D;
      public
        constructor Create(aVG: Agg2D);
        procedure DrawEllipse;
      end;

      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }

        fBMP: TBitmap;
        fVG: Agg2D;
        fEngine_BMP: TRenderEngine_BMP;
        fEngine_Agg: TRenderEngine_Agg;

        procedure AttachBMP(aVG: Agg2D; aBMP: TBitmap);
        procedure OnSceneResize(Sender: TObject);
        procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    uses
      Math;

    { TRenderEngine_BMP }

    constructor TRenderEngine_BMP.Create(aBMP: TBitmap);
    begin
      Self.fBMP := aBMP;
    end;

    procedure TRenderEngine_BMP.DrawEllipse;
    begin
      Self.fBMP.Canvas.ellipse(20, 20, 80, 80);
    end;

    { TRenderEngine_Agg }

    constructor TRenderEngine_Agg.Create(aVG: Agg2D);
    begin
      Self.fVG := aVG;
    end;

    procedure TRenderEngine_Agg.DrawEllipse;
    begin
      Self.fVG.ellipse(50, 50, 30, 30);
    end;

    { TForm1 }

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.OnResize := {$IFDEF FPC} @ {$ENDIF} OnSceneResize;
      Self.OnPaint := {$IFDEF FPC} @ {$ENDIF} OnScenePaint;

      fBMP := TBitmap.Create;
      fBMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      fBMP.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      fBMP.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
      fBMP.Width := ClientWidth;
      fBMP.Height := ClientHeight;

      fVG.Construct;
      Self.AttachBMP(fVG, fBMP);

      fEngine_BMP := TRenderEngine_BMP.Create(fBMP);
      fEngine_Agg := TRenderEngine_Agg.Create(fVG);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.AttachBMP(aVG: Agg2D; aBMP: TBitmap);
    var
      tmpBuffer: pointer;
      tmpStride: integer;
    begin
      tmpStride := integer(aBMP.ScanLine[1]) - integer(aBMP.ScanLine[0]);

      if tmpStride < 0 then
        tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[aBMP.Height - 1]
      else
        tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[0];

      aVG.attach(tmpBuffer, aBMP.Width, aBMP.Height, tmpStride);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.fBMP.Canvas.FillRect(Self.ClientRect);

    //  Self.fBMP.Canvas.ellipse(20, 20, 80, 80);  // Work
    //  Self.fVG.ellipse(50, 50, 30, 30);          // Do not Work
    //  Self.fEngine_BMP.DrawEllipse;              // Work
      Self.fEngine_Agg.DrawEllipse;                // Do not work

      Self.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, fBMP);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.OnSceneResize(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      fBMP.Width := IfThen(ClientWidth > 0, ClientWidth, 2);
      fBMP.Height := IfThen(ClientHeight > 0, ClientHeight, 2);

      Self.AttachBMP(fVG, fBMP);
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "do not work"? What error messages are you getting? At compile time or at run time? Without information like that it you are making it harder for people to help you.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Thank you for your time! The code draws a circle. That line with the "Do not work" comment does not give the circle, or anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand what you are doing here. I think your basic problem is that `Agg2D` is an `object` and so is a value type. You take a copy of it so that there are two copies rather than one. The author has elected to use `object` rather than a class but doing so requires you to be very alert to the value semantics rather than reference semantics of `TObject` descendants.

The quick hack to get this to work is to change `fVG: Agg2D;` to `fVG: ^Agg2D;` and in `TRenderEngine_Agg.Create` change `Self.fVG := aVG` to `Self.fVG := @aVG`. With that change the ellipse is drawn.

Now, I think you need to re-consider your design. If you want to wrap up an Agg2D object in a rendering class, then that would be fine, but you must not take copies of the Agg2D object.

Here's how I would write your code to deal with the problem:

```
TRenderEngine_Agg = class
private
  fVG: Agg2D;
public
  constructor Create;
  procedure AttachBMP(aBMP: TBitmap);
  procedure DrawEllipse;
end;

constructor TRenderEngine_Agg.Create;
begin
  fVG.Construct;
end;

procedure TRenderEngine_Agg.AttachBMP(aBMP: TBitmap);
var
  tmpBuffer: pointer;
  tmpStride: integer;
begin
  tmpStride := integer(aBMP.ScanLine[1]) - integer(aBMP.ScanLine[0]);

  if tmpStride < 0 then
    tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[aBMP.Height - 1]
  else
    tmpBuffer := aBMP.ScanLine[0];

  fVG.attach(tmpBuffer, aBMP.Width, aBMP.Height, tmpStride);
end;

procedure TRenderEngine_Agg.DrawEllipse;
begin
  Self.fVG.fillColor(30, 50, 20);
  Self.fVG.blendMode(BlendContrast );
  Self.fVG.ellipse(50, 50, 30, 30);
end;

procedure TForm20.OnSceneResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fBMP.Width := IfThen(ClientWidth > 0, ClientWidth, 2);
  fBMP.Height := IfThen(ClientHeight > 0, ClientHeight, 2);

  fEngine_Agg.AttachBMP(fBMP);
end;
```

The idea is to put everything to do with the Agg2D object inside `TRenderEngine_Agg`. If you do this then I think you'll be golden!!

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you very much for your help! I will try your suggestions! Meanwhile, you mention Agg2D is of object type and thus is a value type? (I mean, Rob just mentioned it is also reference type.)

Comment: @Xichen Rob is, in this instance, incorrect. I presume he is not familiar with Agg2D, which is quite a non-standard piece of code. If uses `object` rather than `class`. You can think of `object` in the same way as you think of `record` if that helps.

Comment: It's an object instead of a class? That would explain it. People still *do* that?

Comment: @Rob Yeah it's really weird code. It takes an awful lot of reading to get on top of it! I've no idea why the author did it this way.

Comment: @David Heffernan: First of all, `your quick hack to get this to work` is great! It works, plus it helps me to understand the problem! Second of all, your idea of how to design properly in current situation is even more great! Now the Agg2D object is hidden completely where it belongs! Thank you very much again!

Comment: @Rob: Did you remove your answer? I wish I saved your comments of var prefix usage! :D

Comment: Yes, I removed my answer. The part about "var" was true, but irrelevant. The part about uninitialized `tmpBuffer` was false, and therefore irrelevant. (Thanks to the three people I inadvertently fooled into thinking it was a good answer. You helped me earn the "disciplined" badge.) My comments about "var" are summarized like this: Only use "var" when you're assigning a new value to the parameter, as `X := Y`, not `X.Property := Y` or `X.Method`.

Comment: @Rob: Thank you very much for your kind efforts to write again your comments about best practices of using the var prefix!